# Excel: adding data to a new table IF this is the first instance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a formula that will copy data from one column (ID) into a new table IF that is the first time that ID has shown up, and will also be copying data associated with that ID (in the same row on the original table). How can I do this without leaving blanks in my new table?

There is an additional column, "First Time?" to the left of the ID column which might be helpful with this.

[image: Screenshot of original table]

Comment: Is this a process you will need to automate or a one-shot? If the latter, you could filter on "Yes", copy all and paste in the new table. (this assume the "First Time" column is accurate -- which it isn't in the sample data, but hope for a simple solution springs eternal)

Comment: Excel worksheet functions are not good in "copy data", as that always will be fragile, you should use macros for that. (Or use another tool, from your description it seems a database would better fit your need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Write this Array formula in Cell `D3`then fill Right, press `F2` & finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` then fill down.

```
{=IF(A3="Yes",VLOOKUP("Yes",A3:C6,{2,3},FALSE),"")}
```

**Note,** *Excel reads {2,3} in order of an Constant Array, which manipulates several values at once, rather than a single value.*

**EDITED:**

*To get records in continuation (as  Máté Juhász pointed through his comments), you need this array formula.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($B3:$C$6, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($F$2, $A$3:$A$6), ROW($B$3:$C$6)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$C$6))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
```

**Note,** finish the Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, fill Right then Down.

You get this,,

```
A101    UK
A103    AUS
A104    UK
```

Comment: Good point @MátéJuhász, you mean to say that Replace `Blanks` with `Message` or skip entire blank row ?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, now I've edited the post and included another array formula to get records in continuation *(without leaving blanks)*. ☺

Comment: Happy to help you @etcetera,, keep asking ☺